# How can I download an image and display it in a NativeScript application?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, nativescript

I'm creating a NativeScript application that is supposed to work on both Android and iOS. I need to display some images that are in a S3 bucket.

As I want to show some progress indicator while the image is being downloaded I think I should download the image locally instead of just setting the source property of the Image component. What is the best thing to do?

Answer (score 5):

After a little bit more research I found this sample https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-sample-cuteness/blob/master/nativescript-sample-cuteness/ and it has plenty of images downloaded from the Internet.

What I used is a module called **image-cache** that solves exactly this problem.

Here is what I used more precisely:

```
var imageSourceModule = require("image-source");
var imageCache = require("ui/image-cache");

var cache = new imageCache.Cache();
var defaultImageSource = imageSourceModule.fromFile("~/app/res/loading.gif");
var defaultNotFoundImageSource = imageSourceModule.fromFile("~/app/res/no-image.png");

cache.invalid = defaultNotFoundImageSource;
cache.placeholder = defaultImageSource;
cache.maxRequests = 5;

function displayImage(viewModel, url, propertyName) {
  var source = cache.get(url);

  propertyName = propertyName || "image";

  if (source) {
    viewModel.set(propertyName, source);
  } else {
    viewModel.set(propertyName, defaultImageSource);
    cache.push({
      key: url,
      url: url,
      completed: function (result, key) {
        if (key === url) {
          viewModel.set(propertyName, result);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

If there is a better solution, I would be happy to learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is plugin available called [nativescript-web-image-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-web-image-cache). As per their npm page:

> A minimalistic NativeScript plugin that wraps just the caching
>   functionality of SDWebImageCache library for iOS and Facebook Fresco
>   for android. Supports local Images.

You can also check if image is loading, e.g. Get the reference to the WebImage view by using angular template variable references and @ViewChild decorator and check the isLoading property (same as that of NativeScript Image isLoading property).